# Is it possible to call an external application prior to latex.exe to prepare a new file to be imported from within the (La)TeX input file?

Tags: windows, external-files, shell-escape

I need to execute an external application prior to executing latex.exe to prepare a new file to be imported from within the (La)TeX input file.

From another topic, I got an rough info that we can use \write18 command. But I don't have an idea to execute it.

Here is my file structure:

```
MyProjectDir
---Main.tex
---SourcesDir
-----ExternalApp.exe
```

EDIT 1: In TeXnicCenter (latex editor for windows), there is no PreProcessor. Only PostProcessor is available. Therefore, I cannot execute it in one go. Executing it manually will be a tedious job.

Comment: have latex.exe be a link to a command that does what you want ans then calls the "real" latex.exe file? is this possible in windows?

Comment: I'd usually use a Makefile for that, but I don't know how easy it is to get `make` on Windows.

Comment: @Caramdir, Makefile in Linux works like a batch file in Windows?

Comment: I essence yes, but they provide a lot of additional convenience (once you have figured out how to write them...). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile

Comment: My dream has come true, [see :-)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25168/2099)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, a batch file will do (*.bat). You can then call the batch file. I use [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com) because of the convenience it provides. In there, you could modify the sequence being called.

Comment: Could you give me an example of your batch file?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Kile for Windows](http://windows.kde.org/). Kile allows you to define your own build options and build chains. You can specify each program you need, the order and the parameters.