# Input files whose names are dates

Tags: input

I have a lot of files named by date, e.g., `20151118.tex`, `20151117.tex`, `20151116.tex`, etc. These in a directory separated by month and year (`2015/11/20151118.tex`).

I would like to input these files without having to have to have the following in my main file:

```
.
.
\input{2015/11/20151117}
\input{2015/11/20151118}
```

Is there a way to do this with LaTeX. I would like a clean way to do this, if at all possible.

Comment: Generating a file list would be trivial with a combination of (say) `ls` and `sed`: `ls -R -1 */*/*.tex > filelist.dat`, then `sed -i  's/^/\\input /' filelist.dat`. This lists all `.tex` files with their paths and prints them to the file `filelist.dat`; then `sed` adds `\input ` to each line. Simply take the list and include it in your main `.tex` file. You could also "do" that in the actual `.tex` file if you wanted, but I'm not sure I see the advantage....

Comment: Related question: [Iterating over files in a directory and including them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78741/iterating-over-files-in-a-directory-and-including-them). If you know the range of dates that will need to be included this solution should be adaptable to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to incorporate my suggestion above into a single file, this is one approach. The shell commands would need to be different on Windows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\immediate\write18{ls -R -1 */*/*.tex > filelist.dat}
\immediate\write18{sed -i 's/^/\noexpand\\input /' filelist.dat}%

% For more info, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25168/8528
\newread\myfile
\newcommand*\readfile{%
    \immediate\openin\myfile=filelist.dat\relax
      \loop
        \read\myfile to \mydata
        \unless\ifeof\myfile
            \mydata\par% <-- note the \par here (may not necessarily be desired)...
      \repeat
    \immediate\closein\myfile
}

\begin{document}

\readfile

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. If you are on a Mac, you need to use GNU `sed`, otherwise the command won't work.